# About covariant component (Dan Fleisch book)

Tags: tensor-calculus

I am familiar with the mathematical definitions of contra/co-variant components of $(p,q)$ tensors as presented in the book of smooth manifolds of John Lee and now I'm reading a more elementary book about vectors tensors by Dan Fleisch.

I have a doubt: as far as I understood, given a basis $B=(\vec e_1, \vec e_2)$ of $\mathbb R^2$, he considers the ${\it dual}$ basis, denoted here by $B^\ast=(\vec e^1,\vec e^2)$ which is characterized by

$$
\vec e_i \vec e^j = \delta_{ij}. \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ (Kronecker's Delta)
$$

Note: In math books we consider the dual basis in the dual space $(\mathbb R^2)^\ast$, but there is a ('non-natural') identification with the original space $\mathbb R^2$, so it is ok for me!

If $\vec A \in \mathbb R^2$ then we can write

$$
\vec A=A^x \vec e_1 + A^y \vec e_2 = A_x \vec e^1+A_y\vec e^2
$$

and the book says that, while $A^x, A^y$ are the contravariant components of $\vec A$, the numbers $A_x, A_y$ are the covariant components of $\vec A$. The reason of the first name given, as I understood, is the following: let $\overline B=\left\{\vec{\overline e_1}, \vec{\overline e_2}\right\}$ be another basis of $\mathbb R^2$. If we write $\vec A = \overline{A^x}\vec{\overline e_1}+\overline{A^y}\vec{\overline e_2}$ then

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\overline{A^x} \\
\overline {A^y}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
T_{11} & T_{12} \\
T_{21} & T_{22}
\end{array}
\right]
\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A^x \\
A^y
\end{array}
\right],
$$

where the matrix $[T]$ is obtained by writing the basis $B$ in in terms of the basis $\overline B$, that is $\vec e_i=T_{1i}\overline{\vec e_1}+T_{2i}\overline{\vec e_2}$: so, in order to obtain the ''new coordinates'' with respect to $\overline B$ we have to multiply the coodinates with respect to $B$ by the matrix $[T]$ (that is obtained in a 'opposite way', that is the inverse of the ''direct transformation matrix'' of $\overline B \longrightarrow B$: this notation means, breafly, that we write $\overline B$ in terms of $B$), so the name contravariant.

I did not find a similar calculation to justify the name covariant to the components $(A_x,A_y)$. My guess: if we write $\vec A = \overline{A_x}\vec{\overline e^1}+\overline{A_y}\vec{\overline e^2}$ then

$$
A_x = \vec A \cdot \vec e_1 = \left(\overline{A_x}\vec{\overline e^1}+\overline{A_y}\vec{\overline e^2}\right)\cdot \left(T_{11}\vec{\overline e_1}+T_{21}\vec{\overline e_2} \right) = \overline{A_x}T_{11}+\overline{A_y}T_{21}
$$

and

$$
A_y = \vec A \cdot \vec e_2 = \left(\overline{A_x}\vec{\overline e^1}+\overline{A_y}\vec{\overline e^2}\right)\cdot \left(T_{12}\vec{\overline e_1}+T_{22}\vec{\overline e_2} \right) = \overline{A_x}T_{12}+\overline{A_y}T_{22}.
$$

So

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A_x \\
A_y
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
T_{11} & T_{21}\\
T_{12} & T_{22}
\end{array}
\right]
\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\overline{A_x} \\
\overline{A_y}
\end{array}
\right],
$$

which gives that

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\overline{A_x} \\
\overline{A_y}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{}
S
\end{array}
\right]^{t}
\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A_x \\
A_y
\end{array}
\right],
$$

where $[S]$ is the inverse of $[T]$ and $[S]^t$ is the transpose of the matrix $[S]$. Recall that $[S]$ is the matrix obtained when we write the ''new basis'' $\overline B$ in terms of the ''old basis'' B: the ''direct transformation matrix'' of $\overline B \longrightarrow B$

Conclusion: the ''new'' covariant components can be obtained by the product of the ${\bf transpose}$ ''direct transformation matrix'' of $\overline B \longrightarrow B$ by the ''old'' covariant components.

When we deal with dual basis in $(\mathbb R^2)^\ast$ it is natural, because the ${\bf transpose}$ appears naturally when we see what happens with change of basis in $\mathbb R^2$ and with the respectively dual basis in $(\mathbb R^2)^\ast$. But if we look only at $\mathbb R^2$ how can we explain this transpose? I mean.. when I started reading the book, I expected to find that the new covariant components can be obtained by the product of the ''direct transformation matrix'' of $\overline B \longrightarrow B$. This kind of definition of contra/co-variant components does not take into account the transpose? What really matters is that $[S]^{t}$ is obtained, in some sense, by writing the basis $\overline B$ in terms of the basis $B$ and nothing else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $K$ is a matrix which transforms contravariant components under a coordinate change, then it is the inverse transpose of $K$ which does the job for covariant components. I think some books are a little loose and simply say "inverse" when they should say "inverse transpose", but this may be to do with the choice of whether or not one adopts matrix notation. In index notation, issues such as transpose are taken care of by the ordering of the indices, so that one does not necessarily use words such as 'transpose'; one simply lets the indices speak for themselves.

I admit this may not be the full answer to your question, but I couldn't see a way to compress it into a comment and I hope it helps a little, even if other answers set out the issue more fully.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that is enough for me at this moment. :)